# How to validate null values on linq

Tags: c#, json, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

sorry if my english is not good.

I am working in a view to do a search, I am using JSon to do the query,

When I get the data from the database using the next JSON:

```
Json(db.CertificationHeaders.ToList().Join(db.CertificationDetails, c => 
c.HeaderCertificationID, cd => cd.HeaderCertificationID, (c, cd) => new { c, 
cd })
.Where((d => (d.c.PlanID.ToString().Contains(planID)) && 
d.cd.InternalConsecutive.Contains(internalConsecutive) || 
d.cd.SecurityConsecutive.Contains(securityConsecutive) || 
d.c.RequestDate.Value.Year.ToString().Contains(year) || 
d.c.DateGrant.Contains(grantDate)))
```

everything goes well untill this part of the code:

```
d.cd.SecurityConsecutive.Contains(securityConsecutive)
```

when the info from the data base comes "null" I get a

> NullReferenceExeption

I have been doing a research and the information says that this error comes when a value from database is null,so the question is:
 how can I avoid it?

Comment: I have a serious issue with people who have nothing better to do than go from post to post downvoting posts. Not civic-minded at all!

Answer (score 1):

You have to filter out `null` instances. Replace:

```
d.cd.SecurityConsecutive.Contains(securityConsecutive)
```

With:

```
(d.cd.SecurityConsecutive != null && d.cd.SecurityConsecutive.Contains(securityConsecutive))
```

This first checks to see if `SecurityConsecutive` and **only if it is not null** does it call `Contains`. That is thanks to the `&&` operator only checking the second operand if the first one is true. Wrapping it all up in parentheses makes the outer `Where` treat it as a single statement. It will be true only if both inner expressions (`!=` and `Contains`) are true.

Comment: @DannyFernández Glad I could help. Be sure to mark the answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and best of luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to put some more guard code into place. If you have the latest version of .NET, it becomes a bit easier to do:

```
Json(db.CertificationHeaders
    .ToList()
    .Join(db.CertificationDetails, c => c.HeaderCertificationID, 
         cd => cd.HeaderCertificationID, (c, cd) => new { c, cd })
    .Where((d => (d.c.PlanID?.ToString().Contains(planID)) && 
            d.cd.InternalConsecutive?.Contains(internalConsecutive) || 
            d.cd.SecurityConsecutive?.Contains(securityConsecutive) || 
            d.c.RequestDate?.Year.ToString().Contains(year) || 
            d.c.DateGrant?.Contains(grantDate)));
```

The `?` syntax is called the `null-conditional operator`, and you can learn more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx.

Hope this helps!